# Postgres Listen command in Nifi QueryDatabaseRecord

Tags: postgresql, apache-nifi

I'm trying to use Nifi to retrieve new records as they are inserted in a Postgres table.

However when I use the Nifi QueryDatabaseRecord (1.13.2) with a custom query: 'Listen test', Nifi throws the following error:

[Nifi Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnxKv.png)

[Error description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tv7EO.png)

Answer (score 0):

`Custom Query` property expects a sub-query so it seems 'listen table' is not valid one.

If you want to listen a table properly all you need is an unique incremental   column in your table regardless of database type

for example suppose you have table named `Person` and have a unique incremental `ID` column. In this case below configuration is enough

[image]

You should check your sequence through right click -> view state
. If you need, you are able to clear state to start again

[image]

right click -> view usage gives detailed information

[here](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Incremental-Fetch-in-NiFi-with-QueryDatabaseTable/ta-p/247073) is a good example about `QueryDatabaseTable` (principles are the same)

Comment: Thanks for the response. The article seems complete. However, depends on whether the table where the data is extracted has a column to manage the data. My solution has a custom trigger that sends a pg_notify() with the row that has been inserted/deleted/updated and i was trying to use the Postgres "Listen" command to fetch from Nifi